# Crash: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, exception, crash

I have a huge application I got from a developer team and I'm trying to just simply run it. It's a piece of trash really code-wise, but I have this crash immediately after spending hours to just make it install (which I did):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

aka the least useful error message ever.

How would you find the cause of this? I see this can be throws for multiple things, but unfortunately I have no idea of its a list or something else, since I don't even know what class would cause the issue (there are cc. 300 classes in this code...)

Edit:

so after some debugging the issue seem to be this: a custom view has only 7 children yet the mChildrenCount is shown as 8:[image]

The loop which goes through all the children reaches the 8th one (which will be null) and throws an exception here:

```
@Override
public void dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    super.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    final int count = mChildrenCount;
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        children[i].dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility); //Exception here on non-existen child...
    }
}
```

which is in ViewGroup.java.

So what could be the problem here?

Comment: can u give us the complete log file

Comment: please post appropriate code

Comment: Posted the full log file. There is no other information in logs which might indicate the place of the crash

Comment: Please post appropriate code

Comment: Actually managed to find the place, please check the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, It should be a multi-thread problem.

I had the same issue and I read the code in dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged carefully:

```
@Override
public void dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility) {
    super.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    final int count = mChildrenCount;
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        children[i].dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(visibility);
    }
}
```

There must be a function call from non-ui thread of ViewGroup.addView or LayoutInflator.inflate or etc, making the mChildrenCount and mChildren array not match, so NullPointerException throws.

But it's really a well-hidden bug. I double checked my code and found nothing, then I used Xposed framework on a rooted device, and hook some ViewGroup's method like addView and removeAllViews etc, I found a stack try to inflate some layout in background thread. So bingo!

This is my xposed hook code, with a stack dump when current thread is not ui thread.

```
public void handleLoadPackage(final XC_LoadPackage.LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    // XposedBridge.log("eggfly: Loaded app: " + lpparam.packageName);
    if (lpparam.packageName.contains("com.xxx.your_package_name")) {
        XposedBridge.log("eggfly: here it comes!");
        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "addView", View.class, int.class, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread("addView");
            }
        });

        //  private void addInArray(View child, int index)
        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "addInArray", View.class, int.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread("addInArray");
            }
        });

        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "removeFromArray", int.class, new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread("removeFromArray");
            }
        });


        // removeAllViewsInLayout
        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "removeAllViewsInLayout", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread("removeAllViewsInLayout");
            }
        });


        XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod("android.view.ViewGroup", lpparam.classLoader, "detachAllViewsFromParent", new XC_MethodHook() {
            @Override
            protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread("detachAllViewsFromParent");
            }
        });
    }
}

private void dumpStackWhenNotInMainThread(String function) {
    XposedBridge.log(function);
    if (Thread.currentThread().getId() != Looper.getMainLooper().getThread().getId()) {
        XposedBridge.log("fuck!! " + function);
        XposedBridge.log(new Throwable());
    }
}
```